# Network MP600 printer asking me to install new driver on laptop

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-vista, printer, network-printer

I have windows 7 home 32-bit on my desktop which is connected to my mp600 via USB.

I have Vista 64-bit on my laptop.

The MP600 is set for sharing and appears under printers in network under my pc's name.

When I click on connect it says "The server for canon inkjet mp600 printer does not have the correct printer drivers installed........."

I don't know what to do and it is really frustrating.

It all worked fine before when I had XP 32 bit on my desktop

Answer (score 1):

If it shows up on the network, you would need to install drivers for it on the 64 bit machine to use it from the 32 bit machine - and you'd need to make sure that it was properly shared.
There's an option within sharing for the printer about password protected sharing - uncheck that and see if it works
Also check to see that both computers have the correct rivers installed for the printer.
i.e The 64bit machine has the 64Bit Driver and the 32Bit machine has the 32 bit driver.